# Quality standards in Error reporting?

Tags: error-handling

It seems not good for me, reporting errors like 'General Error: '+....,

Is there any quality standard in error reporting for developers to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check:

1. [Exception Handling Best Practices
   in .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/exceptionbestpractices.aspx)
2. [User Friendly Exception Handling
   Strategies](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000260.html)
3. [Microsoft Application Blocks for
   .NET - Exception Management
   Application Block Overview](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829026)
4. [User Friendly Exception
   Handling](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exception/ExceptionHandling.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

1. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/page.cgi?id=bug-writing.html

   2. http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html
   3. http://testobsessed.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2007/01/webr.pdf